# Update function just keeps creating instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var categoryFromDb = _db.Festivals.Find(id);

        if (categoryFromDb == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(categoryFromDb);
}

// POST
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(Festival obj)
{
        if (obj.Naam == obj.Plaats)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "The DisplayOrder cannot exactly match the Name.");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Festivals.Update(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(obj);
}
```

I tried undoing my work, since it worked before, I also added a 2nd migration afterwards to the same database, I don't know if that's the problem

Comment: Can you show us the `Festival` class and how you set your `Id` property (or `FestivalId` property) as primary key? Otherwise, I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: `public IActionResult Edit(Festival obj)`: Do you have a value other than 0 or null in `obj.Id` property?

Comment: Hi @Bolts, If you pass the obj without the primary key, it will create instead of update, but you said it worked before, right? What is your 2nd migration? What's your change compared with the 1st migration?